# Move plane diagonally with rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I can move a plane through an RGL scene along any of the three axes (e.g. see the example below), but how do I move a plane diagonally through a space (move along a diagonal line that is perpendicular to the plane, if the plane is not perpendicular to an axis)? Also, would running into the bounding box cause issues? I don’t know if it is possible with vertexControl, but I also do not know how to do it with ageControl.

```
library(rgl)
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)
plotid <- plot3d(xyz)
planeid <- planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col = "blue")
r <- c(-3,3)
widge = rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(vertexControl(values = matrix(r, 2, 6),
    vertices = 1:6, attributes = "z", objid = planeid, param = r),
    start = r[1], stop = r[2], step = 0.1, precision = 2,
    components = c("Play", "Slider", "Label"))
htmltools::save_html(widge, "Rtemporary/Example1.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not easy.  Planes are stored as 4 triangles (because a plane can appear as a hexagon when it intersects the bounding box).  You'd need to compute the intersection of the diagonal plane with the bounding box for each value you want, and then update the triangles appropriately.

It would make more sense to push those calculations down into Javascript, so just the original parameters (a,b,c,d) of the plane are stored, and then they could be manipulated directly.  Maybe someday `rgl` will do that.

Edited to add:  Actually, `rgl` already did the triangulation calculations in Javascript, but `vertexControl` didn't know how to ask it to change plane parameters.  As of version 0.98.12 (currently available only on R-forge, soon in the mirror on Github, someday on CRAN) it does.

You would specify the plane using appropriate `a,b,c,d` parameters
to get the angle you want, then call `vertexControl` with parameters `values = r, vertices = 1, attributes = "offset"` to change the `d` setting for the plane.  Your example would look like this:

```
library(rgl)
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)
plotid <- plot3d(xyz)
planeid <- planes3d(1, 1, 1, 0, col = "blue")
r <- c(-3,3)
rglwidget() %>%
    playwidget(vertexControl(values = r, 
                 vertices = 1, attributes = "offset", objid = planeid, param = r),
           start = r[1], stop = r[2], step = 0.1, precision = 2,
           components = c("Play", "Slider", "Label"))
```

(No need for the `save_html` stuff.  That happens automatically when you print the widget.)